# PHP login script erroneously displays HTML code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli, prepared-statement

I started using prepared statements.  Everything seemed fine until I rebooted my machine.  Now when I try to login, the password cannot be verified.  I cannot console any errors.  The only thing I can print to the screen is the HTML from the initial index page, where the login starts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <title>Login Page</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/landing-page.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Here is the form on the same page:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" id="username" />
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="loginSubmit">Login</button>
</form>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
```

Here is code for login.js (not including validation)

```
$('#loginSubmit').on('click', function()
{
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();

  $.post('process/checkLogin.php', {username:username, password:password}, function(data)
  {
    if(data.indexOf("Error") >= 0)
    {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the process called checkLogin.php

```
<?php
  include('../include/sessions.php');

  if(isset($_POST['username']))
  {
    $username = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['username']));

    $select = "SELECT username, firstname, lastname, email, 
              userlevel, `password` FROM users WHERE username = ?;";

    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($select);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']))
    {
      $_SESSION['user'] = $row;

      header("Location: ../cust/home.php");
      die;
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Error: The username/password combination does not match our records.";
    }
  });
?>
```

I think the hangup is at password_verify in the checkLogin.php script.  It skips to the else whether the password is correct or not.  But instead of seeing the error message, all I see is HTML code for initial login page.

I swear, all of this was working before I rebooted my machine.  This is not limited to Chrome.  All of the browsers are doing the same thing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Was I not clear?  Please specify.

Comment: Is the database running on your computer? (Maybe it was a service on your computer and it didn't restarted) Or may the link with the database broken?

Comment: Does this happen if you enter both a valid password and invalid password?

Comment: @JamesLingham - That is correct.  I can enter a valid or invalid password, and I get the same results, which is HTML code.

Comment: @TakitIsy - The database connection and service is good.

Comment: when an invalid password is used, does it display the error message you have included?

Comment: Try var dump or printing the $_POST array and seeing if username is infact being posted. If the conditional if going straight to else, it may not be set.

Comment: @JamesLingham - The error message is what I should at least be seeing, but all I'm seeing the HTML code.

Comment: Also when you do `console.log(username);` do you get anything. Trying to figure out if this is really server side or client side. Or you can use the network tab to check the http request out.

Comment: Are you running this through a web server, or just accessing the local HTML file? In other words, does the address in the browser look like `http://localhost` (or `https`, or `...testserver.dev`, or whatever), or does it look like `file:///C:/something`? You have to run it through a server or the PHP will not be executed.

Comment: @JohnBeasley what html markup are you seeing. I think we all are assuming you were getting the response of Error: The username/password combination does not match our records.

Comment: @pj100 - I am seeing all of the HTML for the login page, starting with the doctype above down the closing HTML tags.

Comment: It appears I am not even getting to the checkLogin.php script.  I just attempted to echo "hello" and the console still read HTML code.  -  I AM LOSING MY MIND.  I've never seen this before.

Comment: if you manually execute `checkLogin.php` you should see the error message text. Does that happen? By default no $_POST would be set, inherently. Do this without using XHR, just manually navigate to /process/checkLogin.php.

Comment: In your browser developper's console under the network tab do you see what you are querying? And what's the server response code?

Comment: I just added an edit to my code.  I think I found the problem.

Comment: Upvotes for everyone.  I was able to remove seeing the HTML code.  I can now see the correct error message.  I am having a problem logging in, but I think I can figure it out now.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I think I found the problem. I should have posted the code for sessions.php, which looks like this:

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();} 
  include("database.php");

  $username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
  $firstname = $_SESSION['user']['firstname'];
  // few more sessions

  if(empty($_SESSION['user']['username']) || $_SESSION['user']['userlevel'] != '9')
  {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    die;
  }
?>
```

I think the problem was in the sessions, in that if statement above. I was trying to prevent people from accessing the sessions page or any other page, and when I removed that if statement, I am now able to achieve successful results.